# Finding the biggest union of disjoint sets from given sets

Tags: algorithm, graph, intersection

I have multiple sets (about 100 or so) of numbers ranging from 1 to 32, each one have no more than 32 items.

For example:

```
[1,2]
[3,4]
[1,2,3]
```

What I'm trying to do is to make an algorithm to output the biggest union of sets, which don't have intersections with each other.

An output from the example is `[[1,2], [3,4]]`, where they don't have any intersections with each other, and the union of them are bigger than the set `[[1,2,3]]`.

I've tried finding the maximum match of a bipartite graph with sets mapped to the numbers, but I was immediately confused, as the problem is not about finding only one matching, but a set to multiple numbers.

It seems that writing a algorithm of polynomial time complexity is hard, any ideas of no more than 2^n time complexity would be appreciated.

Comment: Zero one integer programming would be my first pick. There are good open source solvers like cbc.

Comment: If the sets contain integers ranging from 1-32, they can't have 50 members (or anything over 32).

Comment: please explain what you mean when you say that each set can have no more than 50 items. I doesn't seem to make sense, given that each set can only contain numbers in the range 1 to 32. Please also state a preferred language. 32 seems a good fit for speeding things up by using 32-bit integers.

Comment: @WalterTross that sounds like a good micro-optimization, but I think the question is asking for a better algorithm altogether.

Comment: sorry for giving wrong data ranges, the range is now fixed.

Comment: @WalterTross the way to check if two sets have no intersections I worked out so far is to check if set1 ^ set2 == set1 | set2, using bit operations, but it won't do much if there's a test set of over 20 set if the overall time complexity is 2^n in worst situation.

Comment: funny you are not using `(set1 & set 2) == 0` (also beware: parentheses are needed!)

Comment: I think you should change the title of your question, because you explain that you are looking for the biggest union of disjoint sets, not for the maximum number of disjoint sets.

Comment: @WalterTross It looks like I'm thinking it in some complicated ways, a simple & operand can check this for sure.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you’re describing is called the [set-packing problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_packing) and is known to be NP-hard. As a result, we don’t know of any polynomial-time algorithms for this problem, and if P ≠ NP then none exist.

Comment: So should I'm going to brute-force it? The only solution I found is to iterate through the sets with a bfs-like method, which has a time complexity ranging from n to 2^n where n is the number of sets, and a space complexity of 2^n*log2(σ) where σ stands for the dictionary size from my consideration, and it seemed to be over complicated when there are many sets to take in the worst situation.

Comment: It's possible that there's something better than brute force but which still takes exponential time, though I'm not aware of it. At some level, most solutions will work by doing some sort of exploration over possible combinations.

Comment: the OP's problem is similar to the set-packing problem, but different, since the OP is looking for the union with the maximum number of elements, not for the union with the maximum number of subsets.

Answer (score 0):

In the general case of 100 random subsets of {1..32}, a basic exhaustive search works quite well. The size of a subset will be around 16, and if you pick 100 of them, quite often no pair will be disjoint. So that's roughly n^2/2 comparisons (if the subsets are randomly picked).

In the special case when the length of the subsets is small (5 for example), then the complexity goes up much faster. A basic exhaustive search should work at least for up to 500.

My point is that it depends on your data.